# Navigation Bar Items disappearing while using MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, swift

I am using **MMDrawerController** to navigate through various views in my app one of which is a **TabBarController** which has 5 further views linked to each of its 5 bar items. Each of those 5 views have navigation bar items attached to them. The left bar Item on each of these 5 views toggles the **LeftViewController** (The view that I use as my drawer). I am using this code in my **AppDelegate** to achieve this

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! TabBarController

    var leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController

    var leftsideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
    var centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerViewController, leftDrawerViewController: leftViewController)

    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView
```

and I am calling this method when the left bar buttons are tapped on the 5 ViewControllers

```
@IBAction func leftButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Works perfectly so far.

Now I have a tableView in my **LeftViewController** in which I wish to achieve the following behaviour - clicking on the first row navigates us to the **TabBarController** while the second row takes us to another **ViewController** and with `withFullCloseAnimation` set to `true`.

Here is the code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of the **LeftViewController**'s tableView

```
var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        var centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! TabBarController
        var centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        appDelegate.centerContainer?.setCenterViewController(centerNav, withFullCloseAnimation: true, completion: nil)
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break;
```

This makes the navigation bar items of the 5 views in the TabBarController disappear. It works fine if I use this -

```
var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break;
```

1. The last bit of code makes me think it is initiating the **TabBarController** all over again rather than 'restoring' the one that had already been initalised. Is that so?
2. What should be the right way to achieve this?

Sorry for the length of the question (just increased it further by typing this)

Answer (score -1):

I added  .navigationController

in the  didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController centerViewController.navigationController

```
        break;
```